# Stop Chrome extension to override original page's css

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I've created an extension which will be added on every page user visits and do some stuff depending on their domain name. 
Here is my manifest.js file

```
{
  ...
    "version": "2.9",
    "background": {
      "scripts": [ "js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js", "js/background.js","js/select2.min.js","js/lodash.js","js/bootstrap.min.js","js/bootstrap-select.min.js" ]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
    {   
        "css": ["css/extension_website_result.css","css/bootstrap.min.css","css/bootstrap-select.min.css","css/select2.css" ],
        "js": [ "js/common.js" , "js/lodash.js", "js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js", "js/jsapi.js", "js/select2.min.js" ,"js/bootstrap.min.js","js/bootstrap-select.min.js", "js/extension_site_search_result.js" ],
        "exclude_matches": [ "*://*.google.com/search*", "*://*.google.com.au/*", "*://*.linkedin.com/profile/view*", "*://*.linkedin.com/in/*", "*://*.linkedin.com/pub/*", "*://*.linkedin.com/recruiter/profile/*", "*://*.linkedin.com/vsearch/*", "*://*.linkedin.com/sales/accounts*", "*://*.linkedin.com/cap/peopleSearch/*", "*://*.linkedin.com/recruiter/search*", "*://*.linkedin.com/sales/profile/*", "*://*.linkedin.com/sales/search*" , "*://*.mail.google.com/*", "*://*.dev.found.ly/*", "*://*.demo.found.ly/*" ],
        "exclude_globs":  ["*://*.google.*/*"],
        "matches": [ "<all_urls>"]
    }
      ],
    ...
  }
```

`exclude_matches` & `exclude_globs` will not run this extension as I have added other pages for these pages. So now if user visits any other pages the extension will call `js/extension_site_search_result` and do some stuff on `document.ready` and load extension page with css `css/extension_website_result.css`.

this works great. But on some sites the extension css is interfering with main site's css and messing up the design.
i have tried `"run_at": "document_idle"` but still it won't work.
any ideas? I think the css is loading at the same time DOM is loading and thus this interference. Any one knows good practice for working with Chrome CSS? Or is there any way i can include css in js file after `docuemnt.ready` to avoid issues. Don't know how to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to append css after the document has loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(screen.width > 1024) {
     $('head').append('<link href='file.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />')
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks @Simon, It turns out css/bootstrap.min.css was creating problems and i just override it and added just necessary part of it. Thanks for the help tho.